# saving values from an input field

Tags: php, html, wordpress, validation, forms

hi Iam trying to create a wordpress plugin option page.I need to create a form with input fields having default values in it and when I change the value and save it, the changed value should be reflected in the input filed and also in the variable which are assigned to store the value.

let me be more precise

When i change the value of the input field and save it it should be stored in the assiged variable value( permanently till i again change it myself).

Iam a bit poor in form validation and php.help me out guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with it only working in newer browsers, you could use the placeholder attribute on the text field, to supply a placeholder that will disappear when you focus and reappear when you blur.

```
<input type="text" name="txtfield" value="" placeholder="input your text" />
```

If you want it to work in older browsers, do it in javascript:

```
<input type="text" name="txtfield" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Email')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Email'" >
```

Then you can use `<?php $value = $_post['txtfield'] ?>` to assign the input value to a variable.

Comment: But if i refresh it the $value data is lost, i need to store it, till i edit it and save it again.

Comment: Why you need to refresh the page? in that case you have to do it in cookies or session variable.

Comment: how to implement it using sessions variable? If you have any example please share it.

Comment: You should at least have a basic understanding of session variables to use them. You can start by reading beginner's php books, however there are some some resources freely available on the net, just google it.